# Bijection between conjugates and right cosets of centralizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

I recently started studying undergraduate algebra, and I came across a proof about the right cosets of the centralizer and the conjugacy class.

As for notation, let $G$ be a group, and fix $a\in G$. Denote the centralizer of $a$ by $C_G(a)=\{g\in G:ga=ag\}$ and the conjugacy class of $a$ as $\{g^{-1}ag:g\in G\}$.

The theorem states that **there is a bijection between the right cosets of $C_G(a)$ and the conjugates of $a$.** However, instead of explicitly defining a bijective function between $\{g^{-1}ag\}$ and $C_G(a)$, the proof does the following:

> **Proof.** If $x,y\in G$ are in the same right coset, then $y=cx$ for some $c\in C_G(a)$. Thus $y^{-1}ay=x^{-1}c^{-1}acx=x^{-1}c^{-1}cax=x^{-1}ax$. Conversely, if $y^{-1}ay=x^{-1}ax$ then $xy^{-1}a=axy^{-1}$ and $xy^{-1}\in C_G(a)$ giving $x,y$ are in the same right coset. $\blacksquare$

The algebra/manipulation is all straightforward, but I'm struggling to understand what this proof is actually doing. My rough understanding of this proof is that:

> If two conjugates of $a$ are equal (call them $x^{-1}ax$ and $y^{-1}ay$), then $x$ and $y$ are in the same right coset of $C_G(a)$.
>
> If two elements $x,y$ are in the same right coset of $C_G(a)$, then $x^{-1}ax=y^{-1}ay$.

Is this interpretation correct? And if so, why does this show a bijection between the right cosets and the conjugates?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you studied the orbit-stabilizer theorem yet? This is also an easy consequence of that theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the proof shows, the elements of a given (fixed) coset of $C=C_G(a)$ all end up giving the same outcome, and hence we can define a function $f$ from the set of right cosets of $C$ to the set of conjugates of $a$ by $f(Cx) = x^{-1}ax$. That this is well defined is the thing the author actually proves when they show that the conjugate is independent of the choice of representative. Thus, $f(Cx) = f(Cy)$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are in the same right coset of $C$.

The other direction will also show that there exists a well defined function going the opposite direction. Suppose $x, y\in G$ are such that $x^{-1}ax=y^{-1}ay$. As the author shows, this leads to $xy^{-1}\in C$, and this means that $Cx = Cy$: $xy^{-1} = c \Leftrightarrow x = cy$ for some $c\in C$. Thus, we may define a function $g$ by $g(x^{-1}ax)=Cx$. It follows that, with the same $y$ as before, $f(y^{-1}ay)=Cy=Cx=f(x^{-1}ax)$, as desired.

Now, let's compose them. $(g\circ f)(Cx) = g(x^{-1}ax)=Cx$ and $(f\circ g)(x^{-1}ax)=f(Cx)=x^{-1}ax$, so the composites are identities, and so $f$ and $g$ are mutual inverses. That's how you get the bijection(s). The same thing can also be done if you just switch right cosets to left ones.

Comment: Thanks! But in the original proof, what does it mean, intuitively, when $x^{-1}ax=y^{-1}ay$ implies $x$ and $y$ are in the same right coset of $C$? Why are we concerned about $x$ and $y$ in the first place?

Comment: $C$ is the centraliser of $a$, or the set of all the elements of $c\in G$ such that $c^{-1}ac=a$. What is going on is that if $x^{-1}ax = y^{-1}ay$, then we have $(xy^{-1})^{-1}a(xy^{-1}) = a$ which means that $xy^{-1}$ is in the centraliser of $a$. If you let $G$ act on itself by conjugation, then $xy^{-1}$ is one of the elements that keep $a$ fixed. Why care about $x$ and $y$? Because cosets are not elements but subsets of the group, and so you need some element of the coset if you want to do anything. The proof shows that the choice of element is irrelevant, only the coset is important.

Comment: You ask: "Why are we concerned about $x$ and $y$ in the first place?" Answer: Because you are *given* two conjugates of $a$, (translation: you are *given* two elements $x,y \in G$ and the corresponding conjugates $x^{-1} a x$, $y^{-1} a y$); you then *assume* that those two conjugates are equal (translation: you assume $x^{-1} a x = y^{-1} a y$); and then, using that assumption, you must *prove* that $x$ and $y$ are in the same right coset of $C=C_G(a)$ (translation: you must prove $Cx=Cy$).